# someting wrong with jquery/ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, form-data

i have this bit of code bellow, and when i tried to display data in a console.log() it gaves me this in browser console :

```
formDataformData : [object FormData]
app.js:4946 btnName : dwfrm_requestpassword_sendbtnValue : Valider
app.js:4947 url : https://dev05-eu01-smcp.demandware.net/on/demandware.store/Sites-Claudie-FR-Site/fr_FR/Account-PasswordResetDialog/C2052345030
app.js:4948 html : [object Object]
```

This is my code :

```
$("#PasswordResetForm").on("submit", function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var url = $(this).attr('action');
                    var form = $(this);
                    var formData = new FormData(this);


                    var btnName = $('.requestpassword-submit').attr('name').toString(),
                    btnValue =  $('.requestpassword-submit').val().toString();

                    formData.append(btnName,btnValue);
                    var url = $("#PasswordResetForm").attr('action');
                    if (url.indexOf('?') == -1 )
                    {
                    url+='?';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    url += '&'
                    }
                    url += form.serialize();
                    url = app.util.appendParamToURL(url, jQuery(this).attr('name'), "submit");

                    console.log("formDataformData : " +  formData ); 
                    $.ajax({
                        url : url,
                        data: formData,
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        success : function (response) {
                            var $html = $(response).find('.resetPasswordConfirm'); 
                            $(response).append($html); 
                            console.log("btnName : " + btnName +  "btnValue : "+ btnValue);
                            console.log("url : " + url);
                            console.log("html : " + $html);
                    }
                });
            })
```

Actually, i want to add a div with "resetPasswordConfirm" id , to the DOM, knowing that this div does not exist yet in the DOM. but when user clicks on the submit button , the code must add the div in the DOM

This is the div :

```
<div class="resetPasswordConfirm">
    <h1> HELLO </h1>

    <p> hello world</p>
    <iscomment>
        <p><a href="${URLUtils.httpsHome()}">${Resource.msg('passwordresetconfirm.homepagelink','account',null)}</a></p>
    </iscomment>
</div>
```

And this is the form :

```
<form action="${URLUtils.continueURL()}"  method="post"   id="PasswordResetForm" name="${pdict.CurrentForms.requestpassword.htmlName}">
        <div class="clearfix"></div>

               ....
            <button class="requestpassword-submit button-style blue-button" type="submit" value="${Resource.msg('passwordreset.button','account',null)}" 
                        name="${pdict.CurrentForms.requestpassword.send.htmlName}" >
                    ${Resource.msg('passwordreset.button','account',null)}
            </button>

            <input type="hidden" name="${pdict.CurrentForms.requestpassword.secureKeyHtmlName}" value="${pdict.CurrentForms.requestpassword.secureKeyValue}"/>

        ....
        </fieldset>

    </form>
```

Thank you

Comment: Change the append to `$("#PasswordResetForm").append($html);` or to whereever you want the html to appear.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but still have the issue, i don't see the div in DOM

Comment: Please `console.log("html : " + $html.length);` and `console.log("html : " + $html.html());`

Comment: i have this :
 html : 0
html : null

Comment: var $html = $(response).find('.resetPasswordConfirm');  IS EMPTY because it can't find it in DOM, thediv was  not added to DOM

Comment: Don't know. Try `console.log(typeof response);` and `console.log(response);`

Comment: it shows this : 
string 
and the html code but the concerning div (<div class="resetPasswordConfirm">
)  does not exist

Comment: Try `var $html = $('<div>'+response+'</div>').find('.resetPasswordConfirm');`.